# How to check if an IP address is active or dead ? with php

Tags: php, ip

How to check if an IP address is active or dead ? with php

Comment: What is meant by active or dead? You also need to consider firewalls.

Comment: dead? like bleeding in the the corner dead?

Comment: @jakub: the dead don't bleed. they just stumble around wanting brains and getting shot with peas and watermelons.

Comment: What exactly is the point of this 'alive/dead' request? Please re-phrase your question, we may have better solutions for something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an IP address on a network, or a server IP address?  You could use PHP's exec command;

```
$output = exec('ping 127.0.0.1');
```

output will equal the executed command output;

Comment: or it could drop ICMP or be firewalled, in which case won't work at all

Comment: Ping cannot tell that. It can only tell it is active - it cannot tell if it is dead. It is possible that it active but the packets will get burned by the firewall.

Comment: Depends on what the application is used for and if they are specifically setting up a firewall to allow this for this application.  Firewalls will certainly have to be taken into consideration, but really all of this depends on what the OP's use case is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Net_ping Pear's package to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Free software"Advanced IP Scanner".It's really helpful
for this purpose.

Naseem